# React infinite rerender, useEffect issue, no set state triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component seems to enter an endless loop and I cannot find the reason. I am using the `useEffect` and `useState` hooks but that is not it. **To anyone wanting to tag this as duplicate: Please read the issue carefully.** This endless re-render loop scenario only happens if:

1. The mouse is moved too fast
2. A user clicks anything inside the developer console and then triggers a `mousemove` event after (for the purpose of explenation clarity I've omitted the `mousedown`/`mouseup` handlers, but they are essentially the same as the `mousemove` handler, triggering a call to every subscribed callback.

Here is an example, but be careful it can cause an infinite loop and force you to close the browser tab
**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/infiniteloopissue-lynhw?file=/index.js

I am using `Map.forEach` to trigger the `setState` of any subscribers on `mousemove` event. (You can see the relevant code below), and I am using `useEffect` to subscribe/unsubscribe from this "update event"

One thing that "fixes" the problem is the following - Check for a Reference Point comment (below in the Mouse Consumer). If the callback is removed as a dependency of the `useCallback` hook, everything works fine. But this is not good, because in this example, we obviously just extract the data into the state, but that `callback` function could be dependent on, say some other state, in which case it would not work. The callback needs to be mutable.

My guess is that the react somehow manages to re-render BEFORE the `.forEach` finishes it's iterations, in which case it would unsubscribe (thus removing the key), and re-subscribe (thus adding it again) triggering yet another callback, which then triggers another unsub/resub and we go into a loop. But that shouldn't be possible right? I mean javascrip is suppose to be blocking single threaded, how/why does react re-render in the middle of a forEach loop?

Also, does someone have a better idea on how to "subscribe" to a `mousemove` and run the callback. I recently saw some `EventEmitter` in some back-end code, but am not familiar with it. Am also not sure if that could fix the issue here, the issue being react takes precedence when updating over waiting for the main thread to finish a `.forEach` loop (at least I think that is it)

The base is simple:

#### App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MouseProvider>
        <Component />
    </MouseProvider>
  )
}
```

#### Component.js

```
const Component = props => {
  const [mouse, setMouse] = useState({})

  const callback = data => {
    setMouse({ x: data.x, y: data.y })
  }

  useMouseTracker(callback)

  return (
    <div>
      {`x: ${mouse.x}   y: ${mouse.y}`}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The idea behind the component is, to write down the current mouse position on screen at all times. This information could be readily available in the context, however in order to render it on the screen, we need to trigger a "ReRender" so Context API is not a solution, instead.

#### Mouse Provider

```
//  Static mutable object used.
const mouseData = { x: 0, y: 0 }

//  A map of  "id : callback" pairs
const subscribers = new Map()

Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const mouseMoveHandler = useCallback(event => {
    if (event) {
      mouseData.x = event.clientX
      mouseData.y = event.clientY
      subscribers.forEach(callback => {
        callback({ ...mouseData})
      })
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
    }
  }, [mouseMoveHandler])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

So every time the user moves his mouse, the `mousemove` handler will update the `static` object. The Provider component itself **DOES NOT** rerender.

#### Mouse Consumer

```
useMouseTracker = callback => {
  const id = 0 // This value is not 0, it's a system-wide per-component constant, guaranteed, tried and tested

  const subscribe = useCallback(() => {
    subscribers.set(id, callback)
  }, [id, callback /* Reference Point */])

  const unsubscribe = useCallback(() => {
    subscribers.delete(id)
  }, [id])

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribe()
    return unsubscribe
  }, [subscribe, unsubscribe])
}
```

As we can see, the Consumer Hook implements two functions, which `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` the `id` into the Map of callbacks, previously referenced in the Provider, that is ALL it does, it doesn't call the callback, it never triggers anything other then adding/removing the `callback` from the Map object.
All of the "updating" is done by the **Provider** or rather the component who's callback the provider calls, on every `mousemove`. In other words, the `useEffect` doesn't EVER trigger a state update, mouse interaction does.

The `useEffect` hook returns an unsubscribe function which makes sure it "cleans up after itself" so that the `callback` doesn't get triggered if the component is dismounted.

### The Problem

Well as I said the problem is, I end up in an endless re-render loop with this component, and it only happens if the mouse is moved too fast or if it goes "offscreen" such as into the developer console, for example.

EDIT: removed context entirely, was not necessary and was causing confustion.
EDIT2: added codesandbox

Comment: I think it's better to use [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) for this not a context.

Comment: your mousemove callback hook depends to noting, so it seems it is just remembering first params only. hmmm

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi the mousemove callback is new every time a component renders. As such the value is passed anew to hook every time, which means every render its a new value.

Comment: `subscribe` has a dependency on the callback, but the example callback you are using is not memoized with `useCallback`. Therefore, each render your subscribe dependencies change, and that causes a bit of a cascade. Does wrapping your callback in `useCallback` fix the issue?

Comment: @JosephD. the example shown is sooooo very much just a `showcase`, the hook is used in any component, there is layers and layers of components inbetween, renderprop would require drilling it down pointlessly. That said, I do notice a mistake in that example, initially the mouseData was not passed into callbacks, rather it was grabbed via context. As it is here, context is completly obsolete since callbacks get data directly

Comment: @GarrettMotzner it fixes the issue in a same manner in which removing that depenency does, meaning it doesn't really. If that callback function changes between renders (and it has to if it depends on some state) then we are back to the same issue, callback changes, subscribe changes due to it, useEffect is triggered due to subscribe, unsub/resub is triggered due to useEffect

Comment: Can you make a demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)?

Comment: @DennisVash apsolutely give me a few minutes, but keep in mind this code BLOCKS the browser tab, its why I didnt wanna put it here in the first place. Will update the question with a "demo" once its done

Comment: What about splitting the `unsubscribe` to a separate `useEffect` that depends on `id` but not callback?

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your example, can you tell us what you trying to do, because fixing this code (for me) is too much work

Comment: I think this fixes it: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-booth-dngiq?file=/index.js. (the id is approximate, but not exact)

Comment: A lot of mistakes? Do you mean in the sandbox? @DennisVash The goal is to be able to use get a function callback on every mouse interaction without piling up event handlers on the window object. Have one eventListener attached to the window and trigger as many callbacks to it as needed (per component, providing the compoenent is mounted). That said, when you say "there is a lot of mistakes" by all means elaborate, don't need to fix it, just tell me what is wrong, I have a fair bit of experiance with this thing and anything in there is probably intentional so please do tell.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner separating the unsubscribe and subscribe seems to have solved it, thank you. Post an answer describing that so I can tag/upvote it. On that note I'd invite anyone with deeper knowledge of react to explain WHY this happens though? Is it as I suspect react re-rendering mid-loop, and if so, how come? Service worker being the one thing responsible for triggering re-renders is what im thinking but i'vbe no idea how react works internally on that very level.

Comment: I suspect it's more it tries to resolve hook dependencies and gets in a loop there...

Comment: @GarrettMotzner I don't know, following the dependencies never ever re-renders the component, only mouse handlers do that, which is why i suspect react hijacking the process priority while the `forEach` is doing it's work to be the reason for this mess. Main point being, it never EVER happnes if you move the mouse slow, which is just affirming this thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` to two different `useEffect` calls:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    subscribe()
  }, [subscribe])
```

and

```js
useEffect(() => unsubscribe, [unsubscribe])
```

This prevents the callback from being removed and recreated, but still cleans up if the component it unmounted. It does seem a bit kludgey, but it does seem to work.

According to the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect):

> The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI to prevent memory leaks. Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), **the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect**.

(e.g. when the effect dependencies change)

[image: Edit sample sandbox]

Comment: Yeh I do not think the cleanup was a problem it was being executed either way. Every render when the `callback` was triggered, the component would unsubscribe, there is no doubt there. The issue is that it would also **resubscribe** before the `.forEach` loop was done, and F me how that happens but its the only plausible explanation I see. With them separated, it is working good now, though as you said,  bit kludgey.